# Camera app.Rotate images Button when AutoRotate off

Tags: android, camera, rotation, imagebutton, landscape

I'm making a camera app. my defualt camera priview looklike this:

http://s3.picofile.com/file/8205079584/2222PNG.PNG

and when i rotate screen. i see another view for my images button.

http://s6.picofile.com/file/8205079818/2222222.PNG

How i can display imageview when i rotate my screen? i set autorotate off but my defualt camera rotate image button. 
how can i make rotate imageview 90 degree when rotate screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. Just i should use OrientationEventListener